# Undefined index when using JavaScript variable in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Each line in my table has an Edit button.

I trying to fetch the row number by clicking on the Edit button. I succeed to do that in JavaScript but in PHP I don't know how.

So I thought to pass the variable from JS to PHP and from some reason I get an error

> Undefined index: selectedRow

when I use this: `$_GET['selectedRow']`;

The final goal is to make specific row editor.

So if you have an different idea to make it done I'd like to hear.

Relevant piece of my code:

```
   echo    '<table width = "100%" id = "contactsTable"><tr>'.
            '<th style=" width:3em; ">עריכה</th>'.
            '<th style=" width:7em; ">אזור</th>'.
            '<th style=" width:7em; ">תפקיד</th>'.
            '<th style=" width:15em; ">הערה</th>'.
            '<th style=" width:15em; ">אימייל</th>'.
            '<th style=" width:10em; ">טלפון</th>'.
            '<th style=" width:15em; ">כתובת</th>'.
            '<th style=" width:10em; ">שם מלא</th>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo    '<tr><td onclick="selectedRow(this)">'.
                '<a href="?editRow=true">'.
                '<input type="image" src="../image/edit-icon.png" alt="עריכה" width="30" height="30">'.
                '</a></td>'.
                '<td>'.$row['area'].'</td>'.
                '<td>'.$row['role'].'</td>'.
                '<td>'.$row['note'].'</td>'.
                '<td>'.$row['email'].'</td>'.
                '<td>'.$row['phoneNumber'].'</td>'.
                '<td>'.$row['address'].'</td>'.
                '<td>'.$row['fullName'].'</td>'.
                '</tr>';
}
echo    '</table>';

echo    '<script>';
echo    'function selectedRow(obj) {'.
            'var num = obj.parentNode.rowIndex - 1;'.
            'alert ("selectedRow: "+num);'.
            'window.location.href = "?selectedRow="+ num;'.
            '}';
echo    '</script>';
}

if(isset($_GET['editRow'])){
   echo 'selectedRow :'. $_GET['selectedRow'];
}
```

I tried also to use AJAX instead of `'window.location.href = "?selectedRow="+ num;'.`:

```
                 '$.ajax({'.
                 'type: "POST",'.
                 'url: "index.php",'.
                 'data: "selectedRow=" + num'.
             '});'.
```

Comment: Try to separate the html and php code. It will be more easier to debug and read.

Comment: tired.
all the data at the page is from SQL at the PHP.

Comment: You are never sending the JS variable to PHP.

Comment: so where is my mstake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your anchor tag href value  in while loop  with following text :

```
<a href="?editRow=true">  <--->  <a href="javascript:;">
```

And now replace your window.location.href  in script

```
'window.location.href = "?selectedRow="+ num;'.   <--->  'window.location.href = "?editRow=true&selectedRow="+ num;'.
```

It will work file in your condition.

Answer (score 0):

I continued to do tests, Someone test my code in his computer and told me that my code works, I continued my tests and eventually found the way it works.

I removed this line : `'<a href="?editRow=true">'.` from the table.

I add the **editRow=true** to the JS function with **selectedRow** like this: `'window.location.href = "?editRow=true&selectedRow="+ num;'.`

And now its working, Anyway it should work both ways so I don't know what was the problem.